# Is there a limit for how many IIS Application Pools a server can have?

Tags: azure, iis, iis-6, windows-server-2008

The title sums it up. Is there a limit of how many application pools a server's IIS can have?

Comment: There is no. Hardware dependent and also site dependent. Too many factors than IIS itself.

Comment: @LexLi could you elaborate a little more on those factors?

Comment: the configuration system allows you to set many many more pools, but each pools' worker processes will consume system resources like CPU and memory. Thus, the final limit comes from the worker processes and that's determined by the sites, which vary in all possible ways.

Comment: Add this as an answer, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration system allows you to set many many more pools, but each pools' worker processes will consume system resources like CPU and memory. Thus, the final limit comes from the worker processes and that's determined by the sites, which vary in all possible ways.